# Is it possible to define custom parameter in cucumber with Regular expression?

Tags: node.js, typescript, cucumber, cucumberjs

I know you can define custom parameter type with `defineParameterType` function in cucumber-js. But only then it can be used with cucumber expressions instead of Regular expressions.
I wonder if it is possible to achieve that with RegEx. 
I am trying to transform a parameter string to camel case that contains certain keywords: `button`, `checkbox` and `radiobutton`. For example, I have this step:

```
And I click on "Create campaign button" on "Dashboard page"
```

Step definition:

```
When(/I click on "([^"]*)" on "([^"]*)"/, async (element: string, page: string) => {
  // expecting element to be transformed to `createCampaignButton`
});
```

defineParameterType:

```
defineParameterType({
  name: 'toCamelCase',
  regexp: new RegExp(/^[^"]*\sbutton|checkbox|radiobutton$/),
  transformer: function(match) {
    return match.toCamelCase() // <= toCamelCase method is injected to String prototype
  },
  preferForRegexpMatch: true
});
```

Currently, the parameter is not being transformed to camel case.

Comment: I think you should wrap the pipes and stuff in parentheses

Comment: I'd appreciate the example very much